# Inserting a timestamp into a table in MS SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to insert a timestamp within a data entry and I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SALES (
    Sales_No
    ,Customer_ID
    ,Shop_No
    ,Staff_No
    ,DATE
    ,Sum_total
    )
VALUES (
    9876
    ,11223344556
    ,1000
    ,9000
    ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ,50900
    );
```

I'm still learning how to do this so any help would be helpful.

Comment: What is the error message?  That would help us here.

Comment: what is your datatype for date column

Comment: Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: My data type for the date column is timestamp.@fa06

Comment: Timestamp in SQL Server isn't what it is in most other databases.  It's just an 8 byte incrementing number, and it doesn't really store a date or time.  You probably should make your column `datetime` rather than timestamp.

Comment: then you should use it in default value , other wise you can change the data type for this column like datetime

Comment: Adding to the other comments, a timestamp column is designed so you can do things like "has anything changed since my last read". Its not an actual datetime. Use datetime for that. Agree that its confusing that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns a datetime, not a timestamp!

Comment: you can use getutcdate() function to get the current date

Comment: So now that I changed that now I'm getting a new error:
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Comment: Your customer_id looks pretty long. Make it a bigint.

Answer (score 1):

i just create one field and insert current timestamp

```
create table t(date smalldatetime);

insert into t values(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

select * from t
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bf41ce/2

```
date
2018-08-31T06:22:00Z
```

So i think you need to change your datatype of your table column

Another way if you design your table in default clause no need insertion explicitly

```
CREATE TABLE test ( aa int,
    dd DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
);

insert into test (aa) values(1)
insert into test (aa) values(2)
insert into test (aa) values(3)

aa  dd
1   2018-08-31T08:08:14.49Z
2   2018-08-31T08:08:14.49Z
3   2018-08-31T08:08:14.493Z
```

sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b5fdd/1

Answer (score 0):

You can also use getutcdate() to get the current timestamp if your datatype is datetime